# What is the difference between a protein and a factor?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, proteins, terminology, nomenclature

In terms of nomenclature/semantics, why are some proteins named proteins, and some named factors?

I've been revising on eukaryotic DNA, and I've come across some proteins that seem to serve roughly the same function, but are named differently. For example,

- Replication activator *protein*
- Replication licensing *factors*
- Replication *protein* A
- Replication *factor* C
- Transcriptional *factor*
- Eukaryotic translation initiation *factor*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**TLDR:** As far as I know, there's no specific reason some proteins are called "factors"; it's just a matter of what name was chosen.

---

*"Protein"* is a specific term meaning a long chain of amino acids. They are typically at least 50 amino acids long.

Conversely, the word *"factor"* is quite a loose term and is as broad as even being ["an element of something"](https://www.biology-online.org/dictionary/Factor). So, essentially *anything* in biology from a chemical to [temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environmental_factor) could be called a factor.

In the context of biochemistry, a factor is a ["substance which takes part in a biochemical reaction… …or process"](https://www.biology-online.org/dictionary/Factor). This could include everything from proteins and enzymes (e.g. [EGF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epidermal_growth_factor)), to non-protein chemicals such as substrates, co-factors. Even Ca$^{2+}$ [(coagulation factor IV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coagulation#Coagulation_factors) and nitric oxide/arachidonic acid/etc. [(EDHF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endothelium-derived_hyperpolarizing_factor) fall under this umbrella - a single ion is about as far from a protein as it's possible to get! So many proteins are also given the label of "factor". In fact, [Protein C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_C) has been named both "**Protein** C" and "blood coagulation **factor** XIV".

One reason various proteins have been called "factors" is that the word factor used to be [used to refer to genes](https://www.biology-online.org/dictionary/Factor). I'd speculate that another reason may be that certain names and acronyms were already in place. For example, [**protein** C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_C) vs. [**factor** C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limulus_clotting_factor_C) or [CREB-binding **protein** (CBP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CREB-binding_protein) vs. [core binding **factor** (CBF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_binding_factor).

But as long as the naming of the proteins is standardized, I see no reason why we shouldn't just use acronyms to describe proteins. After all, protein names can be misleading (e.g. [Sonic Hedgehog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_hedgehog_(protein))), and there is a large amount of [confusion in the literature between names of proteins](http://www.sbcs.qmul.ac.uk/iubmb/proteinName.html).

Comment: Looks like our answers are nearly identical, even down to the SHH reference - I think this one reference has to come up every time someone talks about protein nomenclature. :)

Comment: @BryanKrause I thought the exact same thing! I was slightly worried you'd think I was copying your answer with the SHH point too! I wouldn't have posted if I'd seen yours since you were first and perfectly answered the question but it's quite tricky to delete something that you've just written :)

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious with the 4 minute gap and completely different verbiage that no copying was involved. :) Welcome to Bio.SE

Comment: To be pedantic, isn't protein reserved for longer amino acid chains? With short chains referred to by the more genetic "polypeptide"?

Comment: @JackAidley Thanks for the correction; I've added a note. I was never too fond of the protein vs. peptide distinction, but it's nice to be precise

Comment: "As far as I know there is no specific reason…" See my answer for two.

Answer (score 12):

**Short Answer**

There is no agreed upon naming convention for proteins - there are some rough standards because in language people usually try to convey their ideas in a way others can understand, but that doesn't necessarily mean fixed rules.

**Longer Answer**

I think it's important to recognize the process for understanding what proteins do is not always straightforward. Most often, a protein's function is first understood by seeing *what happens if that protein is absent* (and sometimes overexpressed).

The terminology *factor* implies that a protein is either modulating a process or at least *is not by itself sufficient* for a process. That is, it is named because when it was omitted, some other measurable process changed. It  maybe implies something that has its main function by binding, rather than catalyzing a chemical reaction, or at least that the actual mechanism of action is not yet known at the time of naming.

You would not expect, for example, an enzyme with a known target to be called a factor: it's most likely to be named according to its target and the type of reaction being catalyzed.

However, it's possible for a name to stick from when there is less complete understanding. Something might be called a factor initially because of how it influences some process, but the actual contribution is only understood later. Just for an example, take [Complement factor I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_factor_I). Initially named because it had some role in the complement system, now it's known that it enzymatically cleaves another protein.

Importantly, there **isn't any pure terminology** here or consistent naming convention: in most cases, it just goes back to however the first person to describe the protein discussed it. Some proteins are named (controversially, I'll add) things like [Sonic hedgehog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_hedgehog) - related to the similarly named [Hedgehog signalling pathway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedgehog_signaling_pathway) which is all named because of one person/group's creative description of a related fruit fly phenotype.

Naming something "protein" just identifies that it's a protein, little more.

Answer (score 4):

**Short Answer**
All factors are proteins, not all proteins are factors

**Background**
A factor is typically a small protein that regulates a larger target protein directly by specifically associating with it, or indirectly by affecting its substrate. For example, protein factors play key roles in protein synthesis [(Berg *et al*., 2002)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22408/) and see Fig. 1.:

- An **[initiation factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initiation_factor)** binds to the much larger and more complex multi-subunit [ribosome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribosome) during the initiation of translation, a part of protein biosynthesis (fig. 1);
- A **[release factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Release_factor)** terminates translation by the ribosome by recognizing the termination codon or stop codon in an mRNA sequence
- A **[transcription factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_factor)** is a protein that regulates the much more complex and bigger [RNA polymerase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_polymerase). Transcription factors control the rate of transcription of genetic information from DNA to messenger RNA, by binding to a specific DNA sequence.

<sub>**Reference**

**-**[Berg *et al*., *Biochemistry*, 5<sup>th</sup> ed. New York: Freeman (2002)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22408/)</sub> 
<

[image: IF]

<sup>Fig. 1. Inititation factors are relatively small proteins that interact with the large ribosomal multi-subunit complex. source: [Concepts Of Genetics](http://bio3400.nicerweb.com/Locked/media/ch14/translation_initiation.html)</sup>

Comment: Only problem I have with this answer is there are lots of proteins that are named "factor" that don't fit into the better-defined categories you mention like initiation/release/transcription factors. Also there are plenty of proteins in those categories that are also certainly not named factor.

Comment: @BryanKrause - they are examples, as stated, and not meant to reflect an exhaustive list. It's about the bigger picture. A factor regulates something. Nice answer btw +1. Anyway, naming conventions in Bio are history-related and their systematics murky for sure

Comment: Hi, @AliceD, nice answer! I'm not sure about the "all factors are proteins" statement though? While it's clearly true that almost all factors are proteins and that the naming paradigm is pretty nebulous, I think there are still at least a couple (coagulation factor IV, EGHF) which might not be, since they may have been named before their molecular identity was known

Comment: @Jam thanks! Factor IV is now simply designated as [Calcium](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/factor%2BIV&ved=2ahUKEwi6haGY-MTaAhVLaVAKHchDBVQQFjAMegQIHBAB&usg=AOvVaw0AJWjVUeNIm_WvsVJDWujs). Your other example I don't know what it is, sorry :(

Comment: @AliceD Whoops, that was a typo, sorry! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endothelium-derived_hyperpolarizing_factor My main point about Factor IV was that I think some things are called "factor" before we know whether they're proteins :)

Comment: I agree with @Jam, a factor need not be a protein and, AFAIAA that is _why_ many were originally called 'factors' - because it was not known what they were. Since then, of course, the word has been more widely applied.

Comment: @JackAidley - I thought that non-protein factors were called co-factors.

Comment: @AliceD My understanding is that this is only true where the non-protein is required for the action of the protein.

Answer (score 4):

There are at least two reasons why certain compounds were historically named in the manner ‘function–**factor**’.

1. When you have some impure preparation that exerts a biological function but *do not know the chemical nature* of the component responsible is.

For example an unknown [*growth factor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growth_factor), could be a protein, but it could also be a steroid etc.

2. As a deliberate *contrast to enzyme* to emphasize that the activity is not catalytic. The point here is not the opposition to a different type of protein.

For example, in DNA or RNA synthesis you have the actual enzymes (DNA and RNA polymerases) that work catalytically to form phosphodiester bonds, and then various accessory proteins that are required to bind to specific regions of DNA, but do not catalyse any chemical reaction. In this case the word ‘protein’ does not distinguish the molecule from an enzyme.

In cases where the need to make such distinctions is not evident to a scientist who has established the protein nature of an activity, he may have chosen to designate it *protein for greater precision*.

**Coda**

When a field has matured sufficiently there is often an initiative to rationalize nomenclature. This is frequently resisted by the originators of the nomenclature. In this respect [Fritz Lipmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fritz_Albert_Lipmann) is reputed to have said that “changing names is rewriting history”.